# Investigate the existence and uniqueness of this initial value problem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I want to use Picard's existence and uniqueness theorem to check whether the solution exists or not

I just want to know how do I check continuity of 3y/x and want to know is 3y/x bounded?

Please help

Comment: Picard's theorem is not applicable here as $\frac{3y}{x}$ is not continuous in $S$ . So, just find solution by separating the variables . You will find only $y=x^3$ is  a solution of IVP.(Note: beware of modulus ) It may help you ...http://www.iitg.ac.in/shyamashree/Picard.pdf